# iOS 8.3 : Why is the navigation bar background color for MFMailComposeViewController still white?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, navigationbar

Seems for iOS 8.3 the navigation bar background color for MFMailComposeViewController is white no matter what I do. How do I change the background color properly? Here is the code I am using. Simple and straight forward.

```
    MFMailComposeViewController* myMailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    myMailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [myMailViewController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self presentViewController:myMailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I tried many other alternatives such as changing the tint of the navigation bar, but I am getting the same result. Is this a bug? Any suggestions or tips is appreciated.

Comment: If you can, try setting the background color of the navigation bar in the  viewWillAppear method in the myMailViewController class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor yourColor];
```

This should be called before MFMailComposer instantiation.

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]; and also 
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];